# Redux - reducer is successfully updated, but connected component's componentWillReceiveProps still shows the old state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm firing off an action when I get the user's current location to find markers within that location.  I get the data, update my reducer.

However, when I `console.log(this.props)` in my `componentWillReceiveProps`, I still see the old state.  If I navigate to another route, and then come back, I can see the updated props from the console log from `componentWillReceiveProps`.

UPDATE:  This was due to lack of understanding on my part of the component lifecycle.  Look at the answer below :) .

Comment: Can you also please show the content of `receivedNearbyMapMarkers`

Comment: @Samo sure!  updated above.  thx

Comment: Thanks. Can you also show where `getNearbyMapMarkers`/`setCurrentPosition` is being called?

Comment: Its in my component (the last code snipping - inside the `if (navigator.geolocation)` block).  There, I call setCurrentPosition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the intended behavior! That function is called before the component rerenders, so that you can compare old state to 'current' state.

The reducer updates the state tree, which tells the connected component to rerender, and at that point `this.props` should show you the old state of the component.

After the console.log, the component will continue to rerender unless directed otherwise, which is why when you navigate back you see the 'new props'.

The values that get passed through componentWillReceiveProps are the next props.

Your lifecycle code is essentially saying:

1. Tell me my old props (prior to the connector making me rerender)
2. If there wasn't a loaded script, and now, after the reducer, there is:
   a. If the script load succeeded, reset map options and reinitialize
   b. If the script load failed, log an error to stdout

The doc's on the lifecycle are pretty excellent and can be found [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)

If that doesn't help out, where is the intended behavior of the component misfiring?

Comment: Thanks.  Just read the documentation.  I am still confused though.  If I need to react to the props I receive after my redux state updates, which lifecycle component should be used then?  Will I need to use a lifecycle method after render?

Comment: Ok I figured it out using componentWillUpdate :)